# Responsive background - Would like 100% height for home page but image does not cover at mobile size

Tags: html, css, responsive

```
#home
    height: 100%
    width: 100%
    background-image: url("/lib/img/home.jpg")
    background-position: center center
    background-repeat: no-repeat
    background-attachment: fixed
    background-size: cover
```

Just so you know, I am using SASS for my CSS.

The problem is I want my home landing page to be full screen size and responsive, I have a landscape image which works fine at full screen but at mobile size the height of it does not fit the whole screen. Is there a better solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
    img_background {
        max-width: 2000px; // maximum width for the backgound pic
        min-width: 100px; // for mobile phones in portrait view
        position: absolute;
    }
```

This code will be responsive, so when you resize your browser window on PC, it will resize the image to the width of your browser. On mobile devices, the entire image will appear.

I hope this helped!

(EDIT: this is CSS)

Comment: Thanks. I gave this a go but im not sure how to make it work! I will try to upload an example of the page I am trying to create.

Comment: Okey dokey! I'll be looking for it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap for doing your elements responsive. This way, the element size will change with the resolution screen:

Use .container for a responsive fixed width container.

```
<div class = "container">
  ...
</div>
```

Or:

```
<div class = "container-fluid">
  ...
</div>
```

Or:

```
<div class = "container">
  ...
</div>
```

Or:

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="your_image.jpg">
```

There are more solutions using bootstrap but the basic ones are these.

Check this link for more information:

[Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I think I am able to make the image responsive with the width already it just seems that when the screen size is small the image only covers the width of the screen as it is a landscape image.

Comment: Welcome. You could define through media queries another width and height for your image when the screen is small. Bootstrap is doing almost the same using container and img-responsive

Comment: Thanks. I tried media queries earlier but I ran into a few problems, i'm sure I will figure it out soon haha! Also do you know how I could upload a live example of my code? I think this would be a better idea for help in the future :)

Comment: Welcome. I use to use fiddle for uploading my samples and then I paste a link to that specific fiddle in my question... :) If it is not so much you can paste your code (as code) in the question directly. Please, remember to rate and accept my answer if it help you for solve your problem... Cheers @MichaelHands :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Here is a link so you can see properly what my problem is.. It's the sizing of the background image that is the problem for me when the screen size has a small width... https://jsfiddle.net/michaelhands/9eq38tu6/

Answer (score 0):

```
#home{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-image: url("/lib/img/home.jpg");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    /*Note background attachment fixed not work in mobiles accurately like ios and also on ipads...
    USe background attachment scroll for the same...*/
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: im not sure float left is the right option for me.. please see my fiddle.. https://jsfiddle.net/michaelhands/9eq38tu6/

Comment: yes Seen,
you are right...
This will work
background-size : cover will not work according to fiddle...
you have to give background-size: 200% auto; according to media queries..
@media all and (max-width: 767px) and (orientation: portrait){
 // different animation code here .,, ,overriding here... like,,,
 // use...
 body #home {
  -webkit-animation: breath2 10s linear infinite;
    animation: breath2 10s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: breath2 10s linear infinite;
 }

}

Comment: I mean different animations according to screen size....
then giving that to the home div...
in media queries...
you have to make different animation like..
breath2, breath3....